# How to configure (My sites)User profile services in SharePoint without using AD?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, bcs, user-profile-property

Configure User Profile services by using External data sources(BCS),I already referred    http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1628/user-profile-imports-using-bcs

But its not Working....Please Share the steps for Configuring UPS Service using External sources

Comment: what error you are getting? please provide us more details.

Comment: I am not getting any error, But  i can't import any data from external source

Comment: I'd post this as an answer, but your question is currently on hold. You cannot use BCS as a *primary* profile source. BCS is only for appending existing profiles that are synchronized by other means (e.g. AD). What you would need to do is develop a custom process, likely via C#, to create profiles off of data in your SQL db.